# Are the "umbles" etymologically related?

Tags: etymology

From [Warning: In Bitter Cold, Beware The 'Umbles'](http://www.npr.org/sections/theprotojournalist/2014/01/26/265455459/warning-in-bitter-cold-beware-the-umbles)

> And we show telltale signs of early hypothermia, what the doctor and
>   the National Institutes of Health and other cold-weather cognescenti
>   call the "umbles."
>
> First we lose some fine motor skills, McLaren says, "and we start to
>   fumble. And tumble. And stumble."
>
> Then our cognitive abilities are compromised. "We mumble and we
>   grumble."

Are the "umbles", such as fumble, tumble, stumble, mumble and grumble, etymologically linked, either in terms of sharing a common ending, or entire words having a common ancestor?

Trying to do a search of the etymology of the umbles ended up giving the etymology of the word [umbles](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/umbles) instead.

Comment: @sumelic - yes, I think it is very interesting and the "sound symbolism" issue is a subject that rarely comes up here. Probably it is more a linguistic issue  but it is also an  English usage related one  also.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *-umble* words generally share a common ending in the frequentive verb suffix [-*le*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-le#Etymology_1). Aside from that, I haven't found any direct etymological connections. (Note that it is regular for *-b-* to be inserted between *m* and *l* in this context.)

However, the similar sounds may have influenced the development of similar meanings, and for some words there were other phonetic variants that did not survive, possibly because these variants did not have the same sound-symbolism. Many of these words seem to have unclear etymologies (often supposed to be "imitative") that can't be definitively traced back all the way to Proto-Indo-European.

I'll try to go in order from the earliest attested words to the most recent.

[tumble](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=tumble&allowed_in_frame=0):

> c. 1300, "to perform as an acrobat," also "to fall down," perhaps from
>   a frequentative form of Old English *tumbian* "dance about, tumble,
>   leap." This is of unknown origin but apparently related to Middle Low
>   German *tummelen* "to turn, dance," Dutch *tuimelen* "to tumble," Old High
>   German *tumon,* German *taumeln* "to turn, reel." (Online Etymology Dictionary)

Wiktionary is less cautious and gives a reconstruction for a common Germanic ancestor **[tūmōną](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/t%C5%ABm%C5%8Dn%C4%85)*; if this is a valid reconstruction, it means the evidence points towards the vowel being originally long *ū* which was later subject to shortening in some words. Germanic roots with long /uː/ before a labial consonant like /m/ could develop in various ways in English; this handout on the [Great Vowel Shift](http://www.ling.upenn.edu/~kroch/courses/lx310/handouts/handouts-09/ringe/gvs-revised.pdf) from [Anthony Kroch's website](http://www.ling.upenn.edu/~kroch/) summarizes them.

The modern  form shows a short vowel /ʌ/ which generally corresponds to Middle English short /u/. However, the Oxford English Dictionary says that a variant with a long vowel /uː/,  spelled "toumble," also existed in Middle English (there is also an attested post—Great Vowel Shift spelling "toomble"). In German, the two vowel length variants *tummeln* and *taumeln* became differentiated by meaning, but in English the variant with a long vowel simply became extinct. It's possible this was influenced by the existence of other words with similar meaning that ended with the rhyme *-⁠umble* (I can't find any words in standard Modern English with the rhyme *-⁠oomble*).

[stumble](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=stumble&allowed_in_frame=0):

> c. 1300, "to trip or miss one's footing" (physically or morally),
>   probably from a Scandinavian source (compare dialectal Norwegian
>   *stumla,* Swedish *stambla* "to stumble"), probably from a variant of the
>   Proto-Germanic base **stam-,* source of Old English *stamerian* "to
>   stammer," German *stumm,* Dutch *stom* "dumb, silent." Possibly influenced in form by *stumpen* "to stumble," but the *-b-* may be purely euphonious. (Online Etymology Dictionary)

The Oxford English Dictionary specifies that the vowels in *stammer* and *stumble* are believed to reflect different [ablaut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indo-European_ablaut) variants of the ancestral Proto-Indo-European root. I don't see any way this vowel could be connected to the Proto-Germanic long ū in the root of *tumble.*

[mumble](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=mumble&allowed_in_frame=0):

> early 14c., *momelen,* "to eat in a slow, ineffective manner" (perhaps
>   "to talk with one's mouth full"), probably frequentative of
>   interjection *mum.* The *-b-* is excrescent. Meaning "to speak
>   indistinctly" is from mid-14c. (Online Etymology Dictionary)

The supposed root, the interjection *mum,* seems to have no established etymology and is thought to be imitative.

[fumble](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=fumble&allowed_in_frame=0):

> mid-15c., "handle clumsily," possibly from Old Norse *falma* "to fumble,
>   grope." Similar words in Scandinavian and North Sea Germanic (Swedish
>   *fumla*; Dutch *fommelen*) suggest onomatopoeia from a sound felt to
>   indicate clumsiness (compare *bumble, stumble,* and obsolete English
>   *famble, fimble* of roughly the same meaning). (Online Etymology Dictionary)

Again, the etymology is obscure and sound symbolism is invoked to explain the origin.

[grumble](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=grumble&allowed_in_frame=0):

> 1580s, "complain in a low voice;" 1590s, "make a low, rumbling sound,"
>   from Middle French *grommeler* "mutter between the teeth" or directly
>   from Middle Dutch *grommelen* "murmur, mutter, grunt," from *grommen* "to
>   rumble, growl." Imitative, or perhaps akin to *grim* (adj.). With
>   excrescent *-b-* as in mumble. (Online Etymology Dictionary)

Answer (score 6):

***"-umble"***  appears to have a phonetic symbolic function in a number of terms as explained by [Hans Marchand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hans_Marchand) in the following extract:

From *Phonetic symbolism in English word-formation*.

***Final symbols: rime derivation.***

> - 77. Rime plays a great part in language, .... But its part is obviously more important than has hitherto been recognized. In this chapter I shall deal with rime as having played a part in the derivation of symbolic words. Words may be derived from others as their riming counterparts, distinguished from them by the initial only.

## ***[-umble](http://www.degruyter.com/dg/viewarticle.fullcontentlink:pdfeventlink/$002fj$002findo.1959.64.issue-1$002f9783110243062.256$002f9783110243062.256.pdf?t:ac=j$002findo.1959.64.issue-1$002f9783110243062.256$002f9783110243062.256.xml)***:

> - ***is symbolic of indistinct humming or rumbling noises***, as
>   in mumble 1362, rumble 1384, obs. humble 'hum' 1384, jumble 1529, orig. 'grumble', obs. drumble 'mumble' (1579 to
>   1596), grumble 1586 (see initial /gr/).
>   Tumble 1300 is the frequ. of OED tumbian 'tumble, make
>   somersaults'. With the basis of 'tumbling movement' it at- tracted stumble 1325 (see initial /st/; the OED supposes Scand. origin), fumble 1508 (see initial /f/).