# Why do words ending in -umble have such semantic overlap?

Tags: etymology

If we look at this "sound family" of words, we see that they all seem to be about things going wrong:

> crumble, tumble, rumble, fumble, bumble

(Perhaps there are others, although I exclude *humble*, *mumble*, *grumble* as not very similar.)

Is there an etymological connection here — for example, some kind of pejorative suffix in older forms of English or the source languages — or is it coincidence?

Comment: Crumble, tumble, rumble, fumble, bumble are all onomatopoeia. About humble, I know nothing.

Comment: @Cascabel (whose deleted comment pointed out that "humble" is positive) Agreed — when used of a person's character, anyway. But note that "to come from humble beginnings" means they're nothing to speak of...

Comment: (Plus ca change...! :) Does this answer your question? [Are the "umbles" etymologically related?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/337604/are-the-umbles-etymologically-related) Somewhat surprisingly, it turns out this is ***not*** my "specialist subject"!

Comment: ...and there is this post on Reddit... [Words end in "-umble" seem to be associated with clumsiness, or things falling apart/rolling around?](https://www.reddit.com/r/etymology/comments/6ptkcn/words_end_in_umble_seem_to_be_associated_with/)

Comment: There are only 13 simplex words in English with the rime /-əmb/, which is lower than the threshhold of 20 that [I used in analyzing rimes](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/rimecoherence.pdf), so I didn't treat them. But [the /-əmp/ rime](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/-ump.pdf) is highly coherent.

Comment: There's a duplicate, but I had already written an answer. It took me some time because I'd forgotten the method of posting an answer to a closed question... so I had to find [a solution](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/316139/711871). :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know anything about their etymological relationship; however, they all seem have a common 'phonaestheme' ***-umble*** which is associated with *failures/ things going wrong* (as the OP pointed out).

A phonaestheme is a particular sound sequence that suggests a certain meaning, for instance, words beginning with *gl-* are often associated with light reflection or vision as in *glitter, glisten, glow, gleam, glare, glint, glimmer, gloss* etc. The study of phonaesthemes is called *phonaesthetics* (or sound symbolism). (I have explained phonaesthemes in [another answer to a question asking about the *gl-*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/532065/365490).)

According to [this article](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/07268602.2017.1298394?scroll=top&needAccess=true&journalCode=cajl20) (*Sound Symbolism in English: Weighing the Evidence* by Barry J. Blake) on Tandfonline, most words with the sequence *-umble* can be said to refer to lack of success such as *bumble, crumble, fumble, jumble, stumble, tumble* etc.

Also from [*How to spell the meaning of words* by Trevor Lloyd](https://www.trevorlloyd.ac.nz/paper/how-to-spell-the-meaning-of-words), the *-umble* words, *bumble, crumble, fumble, grumble, humble, jumble, mumble, rumble, stumble, tumble* have a common semantic theme of mild disparagement.

According to [Complex Words in English](https://books.google.com/books?id=sNIFBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA123&lpg=PA123&dq=phonaestheme+umble&source=bl&ots=9CoNx-4Hni&sig=ACfU3U171SdQlVfLj7dv5DPq3katjOvlkg&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=phonaestheme%20umble&f=false), *-umble* also links words having to do with noise: *grumble, rumble, shumble, stumble*, but *fumble, mumble, stumble* and *tumble* suggest 'repeated awkward movements'.